# Limiting the number of threads used by XGBoost

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-multithreading, xgboost

I want to use XGBoost for online production purposes (Python 2.7 XGBoost API).
In order to be able to do that I want to control and **limit the number of threads used by XGBoost** at the *predict* operation.

I'm using the *sklearn* compatible regressor offered by XGBoost (xgboost.XGBRegressor), and been trying to use the param ***nthread*** in the constructor of the regressor to limit the max threads used to 1.

Unfortunately, XGBoost keeps using multiple threads regardless of the value set in *nthread*.

Is there another way to limit XGBoost and force it to perform the *predict* operation using n=1 threads?

Comment: Read their docs and look out for mentionings of OpenMP and BLAS/LAPACK. Maybe it's a compile-time option, maybe it can be done dynamically.

Comment: nthread has been deprecated. If you are using the new version of xgboost, try setting the  `n_jobs`

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue and figured it out. The correct answer is to set system environment variables.
For python scripts:

```
import os
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = "1"
```

would work.

Make sure to put these two lines before you import any other package, otherwise it might not work.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:
Standard set_params with nthread fails, but when using `regr._Booster.set_param('nthread', 1)` I was able to limit XGBoost to using a single thread.

As mentioned above the env variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `n_jobs` can be used to limit threads at predict time:

`model._Booster.set_param('n_jobs', 2)`

*More info*

Formerly (but now deprecated):

`model._Booster.set_param('nthread', 2)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to set the number of threads used for prediction using XGBoost-1.5.2 API, unfortunately, setting `DMatrix` `nthreads` parameter has no effect.

XGBoost uses OpenMP for parallelization. Set environment variable [`OMP_THREAD_LIMIT`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse58.html#x297-20700006.10) to the maximum number of threads OpenMP can use. E.g. `export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1` causes the following messages:

```
OMP: Warning #96: Cannot form a team with 32 threads, using 1 instead.
OMP: Hint Consider unsetting KMP_DEVICE_THREAD_LIMIT (KMP_ALL_THREADS), KMP_TEAMS_THREAD_LIMIT, and OMP_THREAD_LIMIT (if any are set).
```

In Python add these lines before other imports:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_THREAD_LIMIT"] = "1"
```